# Added a image of icons look

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]I want to change font awesome icon onclick

**javascript:**

```
$('#refineResult').click(function(){
        if($(this).children('i').attr('class') == 'fa fa-plus-square-o'){
            $(this).children('i').removeClass('f').addClass('fa-minus-square-o');
        } else {
            $(this).children('i').removeClass('fa-minus-square-o').addClass('fa-plus-square-o');
        }
    });
```

**Html:**

```
 <div class="row orange-line">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"
            href="#selectcountry"><div class="col-md-12 lblHeading" >
            <table>
            <tr>
            <td style="width:280px;">Select Location</td>
            <td class="text-right">
                <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table></div></a>
</div>
```

When I click on row (Not only icon) drop down div will expand and icon changed to minus.
Hope you understand my question.

Comment: provide jsFiddle for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are really trying to toggle the classes `fa-plus-square-o` & `fa-minus-square-o` so try [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

```
$('#refineResult').click(function () {
    $(this).children('i').toggleClass('fa-plus-square-o fa-minus-square-o');
});
```

Comment: @sonalgoyal what is `refineResult`?

Comment: @sonalgoyal your `i` select selection is not correct as it is not a child of an element with id `refineResult` - try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QYwZL/2/

Comment: @ Arun P Johny Its working now. But i have more then 1 div like this. when i click on one icon it changing all icon.

Comment: @ Arun P Johny I add a image

Comment: @sonalgoyal what is the `refineResult` element? can update the attached fiddle to recreate the problem

Comment: I have a button Refine result. When i click on this a div will expand{which was hidden before click}.And refineResult is id of expanding div

Comment: @sonalgoyal that is what I'm asking where is the button placed and when you click on the button how will I know which icon to change

Comment: button is not in the #refineResult div

Comment: @sonalgoyal can you edit the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QYwZL/2/ to recreate you real structure

Comment: @sonalgoyal try `jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#refineResult .lblHeading').click(function () {
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-plus-square-o fa-minus-square-o');
    });
});`